# Converting MathNet.Symbolics.ParseResult to MathNet.Symbolics.Expression

Tags: c#, math.net

I have an issue trying to combine like terms for an expression using MathNet.Symbolics. For the following code, assume my 'cleanResponse' is '2.5q+3.5q=6q'.

```
    private static string CombineLikeTerms(string cleanResponse)
    {
        var root = GetDocumentTreeFromLaTeX(cleanResponse).Children[0];
        LaTeXNode left = root.Children[1];
        LaTeXNode right = root.Children[0];

        var combinedLeft = Infix.Print(Algebraic.Expand(Infix.ParseOrThrow(Infix.Print(GetEQExpressionFromLaTeXNode(left)))));
        var combinedRight = Infix.Print(Algebraic.Expand(Infix.ParseOrThrow(Infix.Print(GetEQExpressionFromLaTeXNode(right)))));

        return combinedLeft + "=" + combinedRight;
    }
```

The issue I am seeing, is that the returned value is still '2.5q+3.5q=6q'. Now, if the 'cleanResponse' is changed to '2q+4q=6q', the returned result is '6q=6q', which is what I expect.

I have found something here, https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/issues/3, that allows for combining like terms with floating point numbers. But, because the Infix.Parse method returns a ParseResult, and not a string value, I am unable to use it as is.

Does anyone know of a way to convert a ParseResult to an Expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow what you're trying to achieve in this code sample. For example, why do you create an expression, format it as infix and then parse it back into an expression? But maybe I can help clarify parts of it:

- `Infix.Parse` does return a `ParseResult`, which is quite inconvenient to handle in C#. That's why in C# I recommend to use `Infix.ParseOrThrow` instead, which works the same way but directly returns an Expression (or throws an exception), skipping the `ParseResult`.
- The infix parser in Math.NET Symbolics does not allow skipping the multiplicator operator, i.e. instead of `2.5q+3.5q` you need to write `2.5*q+3.5*q`.
- Expressions like these are automatically simplified, that's why `Infix.Format(Infix.ParseOrThrow("2.5*q+3.5*q"))` returns `6*q`. No need to use `Algebraic.Expand` in this particular case.
- `Infix.Print` is deprecated, consider to use `Infix.Format` instead.

It seems your code can be simplified to:

```
var left = Infix.ParseOrThrow("2.5*q+3.5*q");
var right = Infix.ParseOrThrow("6*q");
var combined = String.Format("{0}={1}", Infix.Format(left), Infix.Format(right));
```

where combined will be `6*q=6*q`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems I may be using an outdated version of MathNet. I have seen the Infix.Format used, but it is not available in the code base I am using. I will go the route of upgrading to the latest and greatest, and see where that gets me.

I may be back on here in the coming days if i run into any issues. Is that OK?

Comment: Sure. The newest version is currently v0.15.0, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Symbolics/. We also have a discussion board at https://discuss.mathdotnet.com/c/symbolics

Comment: I updated to the current version, and all seems to be working now. Thanks!